# Check for conditions in If - else block

Tags: java, android

In my program i want to show three status while uploading image to server, Status are:

1. Upload Done
2. Upload Failed
3. Already Exist

Still i have implemented Upload Done and Failed condition in code, but don't know where and how i need to implement Already Exist in If-else block.

```
    String strStatusID = "0";
    String strError = "";

    try {      

    JSONObject c = new JSONObject(resServer);
    strStatusID = c.getString("StatusID");
    strError = c.getString("Message");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Prepare Status
    if(strStatusID.equals("0"))
    {   
        status.setImageResource(R.drawable.upload_failed);
        ImageButton btnUpload = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
        btnUpload.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else
    {
        status.setImageResource(R.drawable.upload_done);
    }

    }
```

**Edited Code:-**

```
    String strStatusID = "0" ;
    String strError = "" ;

        try {      

        JSONObject c = new JSONObject(resServer);
        strStatusID = c.getString("StatusID");
        strError = c.getString("Message");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if(strStatusID.equals("0"))
        {   
            status.setImageResource(R.drawable.upload_failed);
            ImageButton btnUpload = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
            btnUpload.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else if((strStatusID.equals("1"))   // Syntax error on token ")", ) expected after this token
        {
          status.setImageResource(R.drawable.upload_done);
        }
        else
        {
            status.setImageResource(R.drawable.already_exist);
        }

        }
```

Comment: oh my bad luck, unnecessary using extra opening braces, now solved

Comment: thanks to all of you, but can't accept all... @Simon was the first person who answered this first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `else if`

```
if(strStatusID.equals("0"){
    ...
} 
else if(strStatusID.equals("1")){
    ...
} 
else {
   ...
}
```

Your code would be much better though if you used an `enum` for the status and a `switch` statement.

Comment: thanks i ticked as useful, but still small issue, see my edited code

Comment: **else if((strStatusID.equals("1"))** should be    **else if(strStatusID.equals("1"))**
Is any other problem in edited code?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(strStatusID.equals("1")){
// Upload Done
}else if(strStatusID.equals("2")){
//  Upload Failed
}else{
// Already Exist or any other value
}
```

Comment: thanks i ticked as useful, but still small issue, see my edited code

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(strStatusID.equals("0"))
                 {   
                    status.setImageResource(R.drawable.upload_failed);
                    ImageButton btnUpload = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
                    btnUpload.setEnabled(true);
                 }
                 else if((strStatusID.equals("1")
                {
                  status.setImageResource(R.drawable.alreadyexist);
                }
                else
                {
                    status.setImageResource(R.drawable.upload_done);
                }
```

Comment: thanks i ticked as useful, but still small issue, see my edited code

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **if else** condition use **if elseif** conditions

```
 String strStatusID = "0";
    String strError = "";

    try {      

    JSONObject c = new JSONObject(resServer);
    strStatusID = c.getString("StatusID");
    strError = c.getString("Message");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Prepare Status
    if(strStatusID.equals("0"))
    {   
        status.setImageResource(R.drawable.upload_failed);
        ImageButton btnUpload = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
        btnUpload.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else   if(strStatusID.equals("1"))
    {
        status.setImageResource(R.drawable.upload_done);
    }
else{

}
    }
```

Comment: thanks i ticked as useful, but still small issue, see my edited code

Comment: ok.
Write  status.setImageResource(R.drawable.already_exist); in else if(strStatusID.equals("1")) condition

Answer (score 1):

Already exist must be an answer of the server.
You can use differents solution :

```
if (strStatusID.equals("0")){
    //upload failed
    ....
}else{
    //upload success
    if (strStatusID.equals("1")){
         //upload ok
    }else{
         //already exist
    }
}
```

or

```
if (strStatusID.equals("0")){
    //upload failed
    ....
}else if (strStatusID.equals("1")){
    //upload ok
}else{
    //already exist
}
```

or

```
int status = Integer.parse(strStatusID);
switch(status){
case 0:
    //upload failed
    break;
case 1:
    //upload ok
    break;
case 3:
    //already exist
    break;
default:
    //do nothing
}
```

Comment: already accepted, anyways thanks for solutions :) accepted as useful